# Place Text to Many Label Fields Using Loops and Arrays in Livecode

Tags: arrays, loops, livecode

Using Livecode, I want to place the text "Me" to all ten label fields by using loops and array. I named the first label with "label1", second label with "label2", and so on to the last label with "label10". How can I do that?

I tried this but I got an error:

```
local arrayIndexNumber
put 1 into arrayIndexNumber
repeat until arrayIndexNumber=10
put "Me" into field "label"&arrayIndexNumber
add 1 to arrayIndexNumber
end repeat
```

The error message is this:

card "myCard": compilation error at line nn (repeat: garbage where a command should be) near "&", char nn"

It points to `put "Me" into field "label"&arrayIndexNumber`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
repeat with i = 1 to 10
   set text of field ("label" & i) to "Me" 
end repeat
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Always enclose dynamically derived object names in parentheses.

Scott's answer highlights a quirk of LiveCode: The language parser interprets each statement from left to right, so when it gets to your line 4 it sees the first part of it--'put "me" into field "label"'--as a complete, syntactically correct statement. Then it has to figure out what to do with the remaining '&arrayIndexNumber', and there it fails because that is not a syntactically correct statement or clause.

By enclosing the derived object name in parentheses you are forcing the parser to evaluate that section of the statement first, so on iteration 1 of the loop:

```
put "Me" into field ("label"&arrayIndexNumber)
```

Is interpreted by the parser as:

```
put "Me" into field "label1"
```